# Access Query Alias asks for parameter value

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT r1.* FROM QueryName  AS r1
```

Throws a box asking to give a value for a column [Date] in a table that doesn't exist. Clicking OK run the query, Cancel doesn't do anything.

```
SELECT r1.* FROM QueryName  r1
```

Fine. No problem

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the query has been previously sorted or filtered by a column that no longer exists. Open the query in design view in the query design window and check the properties.

[image: Query property sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Some RDBMSs do not need keyword AS for table alias but happy with column alias. In ORACLE and ACCESS keyword AS is not needed for table alias

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this Parameter issue just a little while ago.
My error, though, was a mispelled column name. Check spelling again, just to be sure.